# ¿Alguien me puede explicar que hace este bucle?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, bucle-for

Necesito sabes qué hace este código, lo encontré en un ejemplo de programación `php` y no entiendo para que sirve y que finalidad tiene y cómo lo puedo usar.

```
function view($vista, $datos) {
    foreach ($datos as $id_assoc => $value) {
        ${$id_assoc} = $value;
    }
    require_once 'core/HelpVistas.php';
    $helper = new HelpVistas();
    require_once 'view/' . $vista . 'View.php';
}
```

Comment: Tal vez con un poco mas de contexto podamos saber que hace eso. Pero asi como esta, sabemos tanto como vos al respecto. alguna parte en particular te genera duda?

Comment: en esta linea de código deseo saber que hace y como utilizarlo ?${$id_assoc} = $value;

Comment: explica un poco mas.. como utilizar que cosa? al parecer, esta asignando un valor a algo (que no se que es)

Answer (score 1):

## explicacion:

la linea `${$id_assoc} = $value;` no es mas que un truco de php para asignar una variable con nombre de `numero` algo como `$0 ="hola"; $1="adios";`
pero como php no admite esto se utiliza la forma `${0}="hola"; ${1}="adios";`

> **Nota:** los `{}` le indican a php que evalue lo que se le pasa convirtiendo el valor a string que permite ser aceptado como nombre de variable.

**ejemplo:**

```
$variable ="resultado";
$resultado ="hello";
echo "${$variable}";

${"4"} = "bye";
echo ${4};

${19} = "bye";
echo ${19};

${2+3} ="hola";
echo ${5};

${0xFF} ="adios";
echo ${255};
```

## y podemos llevarlo aun mas lejos

```
${ord("h")} ="saludos";
echo ${104};

${ord(5)} ="nooo";
echo ${53};
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente esta haciendo uso de variables variables

> ${$id_assoc} = $value;

dentro del for, creo que para mostrar información. Y posteriormente esta cargando una vista, la cual recibe como argumento, es como un manejador de vistas medio rudimentario.